# Combining the data entered in two text boxes and displaying it in a third text box in Orbeon Forms

Tags: forms, xpath, orbeon, xforms

I have two text boxes, "First Name" and "Last Name" in a section and I want to display the combination of "First Name" and "Last Name" in a third text box called "Details". But if the combination contains the (first name and last name) "Kiran" then it shouldn't display. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you gave the controls the names `first-name`, `last-name` and `details`, you can create a calculated value for the `details` control as:

```
concat($first-name, ' ' , $last-name)[not(contains(., 'Kiran'))]
```